# How do I rationalize higher index roots?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Often I've found exercises like

$$\frac{2-\sqrt[6]{3x+64}}{5x}$$

Where I need the rationalize. But I am not sure how to do it with indexes greater than $2$. How do I rationalize higher index roots? (the above one is just an example).

That is, perform

$$\frac{2-\sqrt[6]{3x+64}}{5x} \cdot \frac{2+\sqrt[6]{3x+64}}{2+\sqrt[6]{3x+64}}$$

Comment: What do you mean by "rationalize higher index roots" in this case??

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Sorry, I have edited my question now.

Comment: Does [this](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/radicals7.htm) page help? If so I'll make it an answer

Comment: You effectively use the formulas for the sum or difference of two $n^{th}$ degree terms, and multiply by the factor you don't have... it's messy though

Comment: [here](http://www.niagaramathematicsacademy.com/textbook/fundamentals-of-mathematics/5-algebra-part-ii-factoring-polynomial-expressions/5-7-factoring-a-sum-or-difference-of-fourth-powers/) is a good page on finding the sum or difference of these terms

Comment: I hope you're happy... I went to great lengths to rationalize your numerator  in my answer :P In general, [this page](http://www.niagaramathematicsacademy.com/textbook/fundamentals-of-mathematics/5-algebra-part-ii-factoring-polynomial-expressions/5-8-factoring-a-sum-or-difference-of-nth-powers/) covers all your simplification need for positive integers $n \le 10$

Answer (score 2):

(See my comments on original for links that explain this in detail... effectively, if we have a sum or difference involving an $n^{th}$ root we take either the sum of difference of $n^{th}$ roots and evaluate, using the given terms as the first factor and then plug in values for the remaining factor... it's messy, but it does work)
$$a^6 - b^6 = (a-b)(a^5 + a^4b + a^3b^2 + a^2b^3 + ab^4 + b^5 )$$
We now set $a = 2$ and $b =\sqrt[6]{3x+64}$ 
$$\frac{2-(3x+64)^{1/6}}{5x} * \frac{(3x+64)^{5/6}+2 (3 x+64)^{2/3}+4 \sqrt{3 x+64}+8 (3 x+64)^{1/3}+16 (3 x+64)^{1/6}+32}{(3x+64)^{5/6}+2 (3 x+64)^{2/3}+4 \sqrt{3 x+64}+8 (3 x+64)^{1/3}+16 (3 x+64)^{1/6}+32}$$

This yields
$$\frac{-3x}{5x[(3x+64)^{5/6}+2 (3 x+64)^{2/3}+4 \sqrt{3 x+64}+8 (3 x+64)^{1/3}+16 (3 x+64)^{1/6}+32]}$$

I hope you're happy... all that TeXing :P

Answer (score 1):

I might called the attempted operation *rationalizing the numerator*, rather than *rationalizing*---which suggests that the operation, like a rationalizing substitution, results in a rational expression.

Anyway, one can use the telescoping identity
$$(u - v)(u^{n - 1} + u^{n - 2} v + \cdots + u v^{n - 2} + v^{n - 1}) = u^n - v^n$$
to rationalize a numerator or denominator of the form $a \pm \sqrt[n]{b}$ (where $a$ and $b$ are themselves rational), by taking $$a = u, \quad v = \mp \sqrt[n] b,$$ which gives the rational expression $$a^n - (-1)^n b$$ on the right-hand side.

Note that (1) this technique generalizes the technique called "multiplying by the conjugate" mentioned in the question (which corresponds to the case $n = 2$, and (2) the resulting expressions are often messy---after all, one is multiplying by a radical expression with $n$ terms involving various powers. This technique is useful, however, for things like evaluating limits of the form $\frac{0}{0}$ of certain radical expressions.

Answer (score -1):

the answer is
$-\frac{3x}{5x(8+\sqrt{3x+64})(4+2\sqrt[6]{3x+64}+\sqrt[3]{3x+64})}$

Comment: Please note if you want to promote your own website/blog/text you *should disclose your affiliation*, otherwise your answer may be flagged as spam. 
For more details, see [How not to be a spammer](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/promotion).